# Install RancherOS on VirtualBox: How to share public key to VM

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, container

For testing purpose, I want to install [RancherOS](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.1/en/running-rancheros/server/install-to-disk/) on a VirtualBox VM. To install it, a `cloud-config.yml` file with public key is required to manage the system using SSH.

What's the easiest/reliable way to copy my prepared `cloud-config.yml` from host to VM?

Installing guest addons doesn't seem possible, since it's not a standard distribution like Ubuntu, CentOS or similar. Blog posts [like this](https://log-it.ro/2017/04/06/install-rancheros-on-virtualbox-and-configure-it-for-ssh-access/) use a *jump server*, which doesn't seem to be a *clean* solution. I think there must be a better way to prepare a RancherOS server?

Answer (score 0):

With VitualBox you can access host from VM by host ip directly,  there are two ways to copy your cloud-config.yaml to your VM:

1. scp: scp is a builtin command in rancheros.

   ```
   #scp -r <user>@<host_ip>:/cloud-confg.yaml .   (be sure sshd service is active in host)
   ```
2. python: run a simple http server in the folder with cloud-config.yaml file in.

   ```
   #python3 -m http.server   (in host)
   #wget <host_ip>:8000/cloud-config.yaml    (in vm)
   or
   #ros install -c http://<host_ip>:8000/cloud-config.yaml -d /dev/sda   (in vm)
   ```

In addition, use docker-machine to install rancheros in virtualbox vm is recommanded.